# Button and images are unfit to the layout in android

Tags: android, image, button

I have created on android application.Here i am using some button and images on this project,
My problem is,

i don't know how to mention the sizes for each buttons and images for the below folders on my android project.

drawable->
          drawable-hdpi
          drawable-mdpi
          drawable-xhdpi
          drawable-ldpi

** if i use the same size of button & images for every folders my app's layout is unfit.why?
Is there any standard way of mentioning sizes for button and images?

suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time !..

Answer (score 0):

Try to create background of your buttons as [nine-patch image](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), and then place them in drawable folder.

About supporting different screens try to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Button"
android:textSize="12dp"/>
```

just give layout_width, layout_height values in your xml. And follow the same to ImageView also